I have a problem with send email by django
I have a problem with send_email by django 
I tryed  gmail and hotmail and email private , all of them return the same error code 

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@custumemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_PORT = 465

Error console:

`  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/smtplib.py", line 398, in getreply
line = self.file.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 707, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/mac-etended/pytonDjango/django-example-4/blog/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
response = get_response(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Volumes/mac-etended/pytonDjango/django-example-4/blog/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Volumes/mac-etended/pytonDjango/django-example-4/blog/blog/views.py", line 64, in post_share
send_mail(subject, message, 'ddddd@gmail.com', [cd['to']])
File "/Volumes/mac-etended/pytonDjango/django-example-4/blog/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/mail/init.py", line 87, in send_mail
return mail.send()
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Volumes/mac-etended/pytonDjango/django-example-4/blog/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Volumes/mac-etended/pytonDjango/django-example-4/blog/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages
new_conn_created = self.open()
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Volumes/mac-etended/pytonDjango/django-example-4/blog/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 80, in open
self.connection = self.connection_class(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/smtplib.py", line 255, in init
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/smtplib.py", line 343, in connect
(code, msg) = self.getreply()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/smtplib.py", line 401, in getreply
raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed: "
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer`

The error message you are getting, ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer occurs when the remote server unexpectedly closes the connection.
You should set this up to your Email config settings.py also since you are using SMPTS over SSL (with port 465) for it to work:
 
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True

However, if you want to use TLS, the typical port is 587, and you should set EMAIL_USE_TLS = True. The TLS version is what I use often though.
Here:
# set your environmental variables on .env file of your project root directory.

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.getenv("DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL")


PS: Ensure that your sure that your email service provider allows connections from your application’s host and that you have enabled the necessary permissions for your email account to be accessed by your Django app.
For further information, check the Django Docs on sending email. Also, ensure
that you updated your Django and Python. Check your system firewalls too, it might be the cause if all the other solutions have failed which I doubt in your case.
Goodluck!

thank you
I tryed send email from my ubuntu server and successed>
